# Confirmations for a contract in Private Network

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

I just established Ethereum Private Network and connected to mist.I also created an account using personal.newAccount("") which have zero ethers. I would like to deploy a contract.So to start I know that we really require Ethers and which can be achieved by preallocating the ether to the accounts in genesis file.So my account was preallocated with test ethers which are sufficient to deploy a contract to the network.Now I have 2 peers in the network, so if I deployed a contract to the network then those 2 peers should check or confirm them, but the other connected peers didn't do anything(like confirming the contract) but I got 190+ confirmations to the contract I deployed in private network.My question is who confirmed the contract?

Answer (score 1):

Read what is meant by [confirmation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Confirmation)

> If the transaction has been mined at a depth of 1 block. With each subsequent block that is found, the number of blocks deep is increased by one.

i.e; Your network mined 190+ blocks after your contract creation.

Comment: Does the link you posted for confirmation applies to Ethereum?